# ASP.NET WebAPI with MVC - Unity Controller Injection Fails for HTTPPOST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, http-post, unity-container

I have a simple Login Controller that looks like this:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private IAccountService _accountService = null;
    private IFormsAuthenticationService _formsAuthenticationService = null;

    public LoginController() {}

    [InjectionConstructor]
    public LoginController(IAccountService accountService, IFormsAuthenticationService formsAuthenticationService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
        _formsAuthenticationService = formsAuthenticationService;
    }

    //
    // GET: /Login/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();          
    }

    //
    // POST: /Login/

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Credentials credentials)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_accountService.ValidateUser(credentials) != null)
            {
                _formsAuthenticationService.SignIn(credentials.UserName, true);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { failed = true });
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Locally, everything works fine. When I put the application on my web server (shared hosting, ASP.NET 4.0) though, constructor injection works fine for the GET, but does not fire for the POST.

Essentially for POST, the default constructor is fired instead of the injection constructor. I'm not sure if Unity is even kicking in for the POST verb (how can I test this?).

I am using Boostrapper.cs and as I say, everything works fine on my development PC, so presumably there is an issue at the web server. I might be able to get some server settings changed. Any suggestions?

Cheers -

Comment: Why do you have a default ctor anyway? That's a [bad thing](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97) to do.

Answer (score 0):

Bollocks - looks like the problem was due to me trying to load the wrong version of the EntityFramework DLL (v6 instead of 4.1). That wasn't coming up in the stack trace, but when I discovered this and replaced the DLL things started working OK again.